# Segmentation fault while "from object_detection import model_lib_v2"

Tags: python, tensorflow, protocol-buffers, tensorflow2.0, tensorflow-model-garden

While running `models/research/object_detection/model_main_tf2.py` from `tensorflow/models` (or just `python -c "from object_detection import model_lib_v2"`) I get:

```
2021-05-24 11:09:02.622828: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.11.0
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I used [this](https://tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html) guide to setup the object detection API and i had no issues, the `python object_detection/builders/model_builder_tf2_test.py` works as well.

`nvidia-smi` output:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 460.73.01    Driver Version: 460.73.01    CUDA Version: 11.2     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|                               |                      |               MIG M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 1050    Off  | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   55C    P0    N/A /  N/A |    248MiB /  4042MiB |      0%      Default |
|                               |                      |                  N/A |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
```

Python version: 3.8.5

Tensorflow version: 2.5.0

OS: Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS (Focal Fossa)

EDIT: Add debug with Python3's faulthandler:

```
2021-05-28 12:48:41.761418: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:53] Successfully opened dynamic library libcudart.so.11.0
Fatal Python error: Segmentation fault

Current thread 0x00007fd3e6de8740 (most recent call first):
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219 in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1101 in create_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 556 in module_from_spec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 657 in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975 in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991 in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219 in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1042 in _handle_fromlist
  File "/home/alessandro/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/PIL/ImageFont.py", line 48 in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219 in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783 in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671 in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975 in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991 in _find_and_load
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/object_detection/utils/visualization_utils.py", line 35 in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219 in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783 in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671 in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975 in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991 in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219 in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1042 in _handle_fromlist
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/object_detection/eval_util.py", line 42 in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219 in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783 in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671 in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975 in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991 in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219 in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1042 in _handle_fromlist
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/object_detection/model_lib_v2.py", line 29 in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219 in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 783 in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671 in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975 in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991 in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219 in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1042 in _handle_fromlist
  File "<stdin>", line 1 in <module>
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to resolve by downgrading Pillow to 7.0.0, downgrading numpy to 1.19.5 (which is the latest version still compatible with tensorflow 2.5.0 at the moment) and downgrading pycocotools to 2.0.0.